# php array index extraction

Tags: php, arrays

I created a array dynamic like:

```
$tmp = array ( array("name" > "rob"),
               array("name" => "bla"));
```

Now i wand to search for the "index" in the array (with elemnt) Name = "rob"

like : give me the **index** for the array with the key "rob", the answer should be 0,
the index for key "bla" sould be 1...

Is it possible to to this without a for or foreach function ?
With a standard PHP function ?

thanks for the answer.

Comment: I assume that if there are multiple hits it should only return the first hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$index = array_search($key, array_map(function ($item) {
  return $item['name'];
}, $tmp));
```

Requires PHP5.3

Or you can use `array_keys()` (works in pre-5.3 too)

```
$indexs = array_keys($tmp, array('name' => $key));
```

`$indexs` is an array now, because there can be of course more than one index with the value `array('name' => $key)` within `$tmp`

Comment: and also, Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_find() in ... on line 1

Comment: Fixed (both ;)) Not the first time the parenthesis confuses me (usually my IDE helped).

Answer (score 0):

You could run an `array_map` on your array with a callback that examines each element and tests for the value you are looking for, though you'd still need to keep an internal pointer to the index you are currently processing, so I suggest going with the `foreach` loop anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Just use array_keys with optional search value.

```
array_keys($array, 'item_to_search_for')
```

Answer (score -1):

The function array_keys :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

has an additional optional parameter where you can specify the value to search by.

Answer (score -1):

You might be looking for: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php